# Loading a .plist file from url

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, url, plist

I have the following code that loads a plist file from the resource folder and uses it to populate a tableview:

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AnimeDB" ofType:@"plist"]; 
    NSMutableArray* tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.dataList1 = tmpArray; 
    [tmpArray release];
```

But I need to load this .plist file from an url.
I tried some solutions that I found on the net, but I couldn't manage to get it working.
Does someone know how can i do this?

Maybe there's an easy solution, but I'm at the beginning with xcode (this is my first app), so I can't find it.

Any help is really appreciated!

P.S. Sorry for any mistake that i may have committed, my english is not that good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest looking into using [Json](http://www.json.org/). It will allow you to pass plist like structured data from a url to your app.

```
NSData *dataReturn = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someUrl.com/test.json"]];

    if (dataReturn) {
        NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataReturn options:kNilOptions error:Nil];
```

If you want to use your plist then its just about the same code:

```
// This will get the plist into data format
NSData *dataReturn = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someUrl.com/test.plist"]];

// This will convert data format to array
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataReturn]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i looked about Json on the internet, but I would prefere to use plist as I've already developed the complete app for using it and the plist will become quite big and complex (it serves like a DB, if you want to take a look at the plist here is it: http://zer0soft.altervista.org/AnimeDB.plist )
By the way tomorrow, when I'll be less tired, I'll try to use Json!

Comment: Try the edit I made. Should allow you to get and use the data from the plist.

Comment: I'll try it as soon as i get access to my mac (I'm not at home at the moment).
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In the end I managed to do what I needed using just this simple piece of code:

```
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://zer0soft.altervista.org/AnimeDB.plist"]];    
self.dataList1 = tmpArray;
```

And it works like a charm! Thanks to everyone who spent time answering my question, in particular thanks to Jaybit!

Comment: If AnimeDB.plist becomes large, you should approach differently. I would say download that file in background and store in cache folder and read from that source again.