# How to access files at a path NSURL

Tags: ios, nsbundle

Hello everyone i have the following code :

```
  NSString* issuePath =[[self contentURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"magazine"].path;
```

I have a file called a.plist in the above directory. I have to read the a.plist file contents. How to do that. Before the file was local and I was accessing it as follows

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182981/loading-a-plist-file-from-url please see this link...hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"a.plist"];       
NSMutableDictionary *plistContents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this file handler utility which provides API's to interact with most of your file related operations.

It exposed API for below features,

- Check if the file, or directory, exists in the given path
- Create a folder in a given path
- Verify if a folder exists at a given path
- Get the size of a file
- Check if a file with that name exists in the folder
- Check if this folder has more subfolder or if it's the last folder

File Handler Utility [Class link](https://github.com/thatzprem/Utilities-Library/blob/master/ios-utilities/DataHandlers/DataHandlers.m)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the following method.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: just read the question.... he has done it that way from locally..now he wants to load from url